# How can I fix the error "Cannot create Swift scratch context" when using LLDB

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

Whenever I run an LLDB expression in swift mode I get the following error.

> Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift
>   stdlib)Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift
>   stdlib)Stack dump:
>   0.    Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb [1]    77539
>   segmentation fault  lldb

it does not matter what I try to import.

```
~ ❯❯❯ lldb
(lldb) expression -l swift -- import AppKit
Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb
[1]    6665 segmentation fault  lldb
~ ❯❯❯ lldb                                                                                                                                                        ✘ 139
(lldb) expression -l swift -- import Foundation
Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb
[1]    7122 segmentation fault  lldb
~ ❯❯❯ lldb                                                                                                                                                        ✘ 139
(lldb) expression -l swift -- import UIKit
Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb
[1]    7225 segmentation fault  lldb
~ ❯❯❯                                                                                                                                                             ✘ 139
```

What's interesting is the very same commands work when using the LLDB within Xcode.

Comment: Please do not show us pictures of code. Show _code_ (as text). Copy and paste. Makes the code legible and copyable. Thanks.

Comment: Noted @matt removed image.

Comment: Do you have more than one Xcode installed?  The swift compiler used to build your code and the lldb that debugs it have to be matched.  So if you had a beta installed, for instance, and built with the beta but debugged with another lldb, that is not expected to work.

Comment: @JimIngham only have one Xcode installed, in the end, the only fix is to start the LLDB inside the Swift REPL. if  started from the CMD line the swift mode import will fail.

Comment: The difference between the REPL and "started from the command line" is that the REPL is actually lldb attached to a program that was built with the same toolchain lldb is using, whereas from the command line you are handing lldb a program that you built.  There's something about how you are building programs that doesn't match the lldb you are debugging them with, but I don't know enough about your setup to guess what that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following conversation works in my Terminal:

```
themini:~ mattneubelcap$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15).
Type :help for assistance.
  1> :
(lldb) expr -lSwift -- import Foundation
(lldb) expr -lSwift -- "howdy" as NSString
```

The success of the second command proves that Foundation was successfully imported. If not, we'd have received `error: use of undeclared type 'NSString'`.

Note the lack of space between `-l` and `Swift`. I do not know why "the very same commands" work using LLDB in Xcode, i.e. with the space. Certainly if you type `help expr`, you get the impression that `-l Swift` *should* work. Nevertheless, experimentation shows that in the Terminal it has to be either `-lSwift` (no space) or `--language Swift` (space), just like most command-line commands. Could it be that the Xcode LLDB is more forgiving or follows different syntax rules (uses a different parser)? I have no idea.

Comment: I don't think that it makes a difference if you put a space between "-l" and "Swift" or not (at least it doesn't in my test). The real difference seems to be that OP invokes lldb directly from the command line, and you invoke it from within the Swift REPL.

Comment: @MartinR That's correct when LLDB is started from the command line the import fails but when started within the swift REPL the import is successful.

Comment: @MartinR what I found was that if I put in the space in the Terminal test, we got an error that the term `-l` was unknown.